# What's the difference between Solr queries "* AND a OR b" and "a OR b"?

Tags: solr

In our application that uses Solr as its backend for search, we have two ways of doing an OR search. Either we type "a OR b" directly into the search box, or we use a filter tool to input the terms, which transforms the query into "* AND a OR b".

In theory, this should give the same results. In practice, it doesn't always give the same results.

Looking at the parsed query using the debug option, I see a subtle difference:

- The first query results in `+(+((content_all:a)^1.0) ((content_all:b)^1.0)) ()`
- The second query results in `+(((content_all:a)^1.0) ((content_all:b)^1.0)) ()`

As you can see, a + is missing in the second query, and I think that's why it gives less results than the first.

Trying different things, I've come to the conclusion that the second part of the query is essentially ignored. If I type "* AND a" I get the same amount of results as the second query, and the parsed query is `+(+((content_all:a)^1.0)) ()`

Does anyone have an idea as to what's going on? I'm using Dismax.

Comment: The `+` represents the required operator https://solr.apache.org/guide/8_5/the-standard-query-parser.html but I am not sure what this translates to in your particular query. Maybe the first one translates to "must match content_all:a" and the second translates to "must match content_all:a or content_all:b" (?)

Comment: An important detail that I should have included is that I'm using the Dismax query parser, not the standard one.